# Why 'super' in constructor returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects, super

I made a **class** called it `Person` and then I made another class called `BMI` that *uses* two arguments from the `Person` class using the `super` keyword. When I `console.log` the two arguments that I called with super they return `undefined`. How to make the inherited arguments return the desired value?

```js
class Person {
  constructor(fName, lName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.fullName = function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
}

let mark = new Person('Mark', 'Stevenson');
console.log(mark.fullName()) // returns 'Mark Stevenson'

class BMI extends Person {
  constructor(fName, lName, weight, height) {
    super(fName, lName);
    this.mass = weight;
    this.height = height / 100;
  }
  calcBMI() {
    return Math.round(this.mass / this.height ** 2);
  }
  display() {
    return `${super.fName} ${super.lName}'s BMI is ${this.calcBMI()}`;
  }
}

let john = new BMI('john', 'johnson', 100, 190)
console.log(john.display()) //returns "undefined undefined's BMI is 28"
```

PS: *I am open to other solutions of getting the same result but I'd rather know what's wrong with my code and get it going.*

Comment: Don't access `super.fName`, access `this.firstName`!

Comment: Where did you define `fName`  in the `Person` class? According to the constructor, the properties are named `firstName`  and `lastName`

Comment: 5 minutes to late :-) ... the right answers are already here. this and the correct name of the methods from parent class. I think a very common mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `this` since you extend the Person class, and you set `this.firstName = fName`, so you need to then access `this.firstName` not `this.fName`

```js
class Person {
  constructor(fName, lName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.fullName = function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
}

let mark = new Person('Mark', 'Stevenson');
console.log(mark.fullName()) // returns 'Mark Stevenson'

class BMI extends Person {
  constructor(fName, lName, weight, height) {
    super(fName, lName);
    this.mass = weight;
    this.height = height / 100;
  }
  calcBMI() {
    return Math.round(this.mass / this.height ** 2);
  }
  display() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}'s BMI is ${this.calcBMI()}`;
  }
}

let john = new BMI('john', 'johnson', 100, 190)
console.log(john.display()) //returns "undefined undefined's BMI is 28"
```